# IE 7 CTRL + click opens a new window - how to suppress it?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, click, ctrl

Is it possible to suppress the default IE 7 functionality when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click on link opens a new window? if so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: All I'll say is that you need a very good reason for redefining actions that users' expect to work in a certain way.

Comment: It does in IE8; this is also the default behavior in Firefox and Chrome - shift-click opens a new window, ctrl-click opens a new tab.  Probably the same in others too.

Comment: You need to be more detailed in your request.  Your actual problem is much more scoped than this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to suppress a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on a link with no child elements in Internet Explorer -- the `onclick` event doesn't fire at all for link clicks if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down.  It seems that Microsoft don't want you to change this functionality out of fear that you might confuse the user.

I searched for some sort of official confirmation/explanation before posting this answer, but unfortunately this limitation is not listed in the documentation on MSDN and Google wasn't helpful.  Nevertheless, it remains true, try it yourself:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello');">Hello</a>
```

You will find that a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on the link will not throw the alert box.  According to [pinkgothic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245790/pinkgothic), assigning a child element to the link will work around the problem.  For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello');"><span>Hello</span></a>
```

This works because the click is triggered for the `<span>` element first, before propagating to the `<a>` element.

Comment: yeah i figured already....i will go with the out of the box behaviour for the tree control and call it a day

Comment: Interestingly enough, `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="alert('Hello');"><span>Hello</span></a>` with a ctrl+click works fine (at least in IE9). Apparently it 'only' matters where the event bubbles up from. A `<span>` is enough to throw it off.

Comment: @pinkgothic: That sounds promising if it works in older versions of IE too.

Comment: Agreed! Unfortunately I have no means to check that; I just stumbled across your answer while trying to debug a site that was mysteriously not working with `ctrl`+click in IE :) and I managed to get it fixed (our case was a simple `display:none` triggered `onclick`), so I figured I'd share my fix. Your answer was a great help! ^_^

Comment: The trick with the `<span>` element suggested by @pinkgothic works great. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method or similar can override default behavior on pages that you have control over.

It is generally bad practice to alter the behaviour of a user's browser without really good reason as the browser and its behaviour is "their's".

Comment: i am planning to do in for nodes in a tree. they are supp. to be clickable but not open links. I am not going to do this for traditional links.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem as the op and solved it by giving the anchor href attribute an '#' and an additional data-href attribute with the corresponding link location.
The downside you need a click handler to follow the link, also right clicking "open in new window" wont work with this approach.

```
eg: In AnchorTag, Use href and data-ref as:
<a id="logout" href="#" data-href="${yourPath}"> 

And in javascript, use    
$("#logout").click(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey) 
e.preventDefault();
window.location = $(e.target).attr("data-href");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your link text inside an span. like this:

```
<a href="test.html"><span>click here!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add script to the anchor and return false

```
<a href='some.htm' onclick='return false;'></a>
```

And it is valid to use anchors in a treeview because it makes the treeview more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can handle the ctrl+click functionality for yourself and return false, for example

```
$("a").click(function(event){
if(event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey){
 //handle over here 

return false;
}

});
```

this works across all browsers including mac