# Ctrl or Shift effects on the `onclick` event of an anchor tag in each browser

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, shift, ctrl

I recently discovered that different browsers handle the `onclick` event differently when the <kbd>Control</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are pressed. They diverge similarly on behavior for for following links by clicking the middle mouse button.

With the following link:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="alert('onclick');">go to example.com</a>
```

Onclick browser support table

```
Mouse    Keyboard       Chrome    Firefox   Safari    Opera     IE5.5     IE6       IE7       IE8       IE9       

Left     None           yes       yes       yes       yes       yes       yes       yes       yes       yes
Left     Ctrl           yes       yes       yes       yes       ?         yes       no        no        ?
Left     Shift          yes       yes       yes       yes       ?         yes       yes       yes       ?
Middle   None           yes       no        yes       no        ?         N/A       no        no        ?
```

Can someone please fill in the question marks for me? Also; I'm wondering if the behaviour differs for each version of Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera.

Finding a logical pattern in this behavior would be even nicer, but I don't think there is one, unfortunately. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694408/ie-7-ctrl-click-opens-a-new-window-how-to-suppress-it/2694627#2694627) to a related question.

This is due to the "expected behaviour" when a user uses click-modifier keyboard buttons - the user expects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click on a link to open that link in a new tab or window.  The chaps at Microsoft decided that the only reason a user would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click because they were expecting that behaviour, thus, such clicks do not fire the `onclick` event in Internet Explorer.

Comment: BTW:

I don't have the intention to change the behaviour of web browsers. I just need to measure commercial clicks (via some JavaScript library).

I got this working for IE7 & IE8 via an event handler. But I'm curious  about IE5.5 and IE9's behaviour.

Also; since tabbed browsing is getting more and more popular (also via right clicks). So some day we'll have to switch to a redirect method.

Comment: There they go again... thinking they know more about what the user expects than the actual developer of the application.