# jQuery click function does not work in IE when Ctrl key is pressed

Tags: jquery, click

I am developing a web app for IE browser using jQuery. We know that to open a link in a new tab, users usually hold the Ctrl key while clicking that link. However, in my code, the click function that binds to links will not be called. I tried the same page in Chrome and Firefox. It works perfect. Why is that? Any thought for this problem?

Comment: Different browsers interpret ctrl+click differently, and may fire different javascript events.  How are you binding the event, just to `click`?

Comment: for which version of IE do you want to build the app??

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023816/ctrlclick-or-shiftclick-not-always-firing-the-onclick-event

Comment: It was tested in IE 8. I just use click function.

Comment: _"to open a link in a new tab, users usually hold the Ctrl key while clicking that link"_ - Do they? I always do a middle-button click (really a click by pressing the mouse-wheel down), and some people right-click and use the context menu item. So there're two other cases you might want to allow for...

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn. It looks like I have to write more complex code to deal with these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what to do in case of a ctrl+click.
See here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-detecting-ctrl-click-on-an-element#14737000000282851

Comment: I have tried IE developer tool to debug it. The problem is that the click function is always not called when ctrl+click is issued.