# jQuery OnClick doesn't work in IE when "ctrl" + "click" executed

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, onclick

I have a jQuery function that executes an ajax POST. Whenever a link (href) is "clicked" with a populated id, the functions kicks off an action.

My function works great in Chrome. When I simply "click" a link OR hold down "Ctrl" + "Click" (to open in a new tab), the ajax POST does what it is supposed to do. In IE, when I simply "click" a link, it works as expected. BUT when I hold down "Ctrl" + "Click" (to open in a new tab) the ajax POST is completely ignored as if nothing was clicked. The new tab in IE opens up, but my ajax POST gets skipped.

How do I get a "Ctrl" + "Click" to be recognized by jQuery in Internet Explorer?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
            var reportNum = $(this).attr("id");
            var embed = $(this).attr("name");
            if (reportNum == null) {
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("updateHitCount", "Base")",
                    data:
                {
                    reportNum: reportNum
                }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

---

HTML

---

```
<a href="https://google.com" id="foo">Click Here!</a>
```

Comment: What version of IE and jquery are you using? This works fine for me in IE9 Jquery 2+ https://jsfiddle.net/x7sap85f/

Comment: I'm using IE 11. jQuery 1.10.2 i believe

Comment: Just tested and it works fine in IE11 jquery 1.10.2. https://jsfiddle.net/x7sap85f/2/. There something else causing your issue. Can you reproduce the issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: Interesting...when I went to your jsfiddle, it worked for me too in my IE 11 browser. Hmmm...any ideas where I could start looking?

Comment: If you post more of your code I'd be able to help, or a link to the offending web page.

Comment: @Vector, I added more code above. The page is behind a firewall, else i would give you the link. I cut most of the content out, but you get the idea. Am i not calling jQuery correctly?

Comment: Clear browser's cache ??

Comment: Cleared browser cache, closed completely out of IE, relaunched and still nothing! hmm..

Comment: @Vector, take a look at my response below to karthik006. I populated  the href in your jsfiddle example and was able to reproduce the issue. Any idea why?

Comment: Did my solution help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a play in IE with your code, it looks like when carrying out ctrl+click it doesn't see it as a `click` event, therefore your click event is not firing. Hypothetically IE is seeing it as a `ctrl+click` (that event doesn't exist as it's own entity).

A solution would be to use a mouseup/down event instead

https://jsfiddle.net/x7sap85f/19/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').on('mouseup', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked!');
        });
    });
```

You probably don't need to prevent default, depending on what you want to happen exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question.

It made me learn something new about cross-browser *think abouts*.

From what I observed, I think that Internet Explorer **intentionally prevents** the `click` event to occur when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is down. That is in order to *manage* pop-ups the Microsoft way...

I also found out that [this behavior exist *at least* since IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694408/ie-7-ctrl-click-opens-a-new-window-how-to-suppress-it).

If you look at the Internet Options, in Tabs.
There is simply not way to select something like a *Don't do anything*.

[image]

I made a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/owGvVJ?editors=1010) to test it...

It seems that the only case where the `click` event is fired is if the `href` is a blank hash (`href="#"`).

So, Like **Vector** suggested, using the `mouseup` event instead of a `click` may be a walk-around.

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette - this is a very well put together analysis. I tried your CodePen test and it was interesting to see the different results. I tried Vector's solution and it worked for me. I'm able to get the "ctrl" + "click" to now work in IE with no issues. Thank you for you feedback! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer is a little tricky . Since you are using jquery try changing

$.ajax to $.post and also 
Add a attribute cache: false inside your Ajax body

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and no luck. Actually, when i replaced $.ajax with $.post, it broke everything. Sorry, no luck...

Comment: Try to use return false inside your callback

Comment: I found the issue, but don't understand it. If you go to @Vector's jsfiddle example using internet explorer here:   https://jsfiddle.net/x7sap85f/2/  He left the href empty. If you put in a URL...say 'https://google.com' and run his jsfiddle again with the populated href, you no longer get the Alert message when you hold ctrl and click. Is this an IE bug?